# Java 8. Eclipse не видит jre1.8

Tags: java, eclipse

Здравствуйте. Подскажите как решить проблему. Я установил eclipse kepler с jre 1.8. Создал проект, в нем написал простенький метод который сортирует лист стрингов, но с использование лямбда выражений. На что мне компилятор среагировал. Скрины ниже. Подскажите как решить эту проблему ?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Project properties -> Java Compiler: тут у вас точно 1.8 выбрана?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eclipse Kepler был выпущен, когда ещё не было Java-8. Либо установите более свежий Eclipse (Mars или хотя бы Luna), либо (если вам почему-то именно Kepler нужен) проверьте, что у вас установлен [пакет обновлений](https://wiki.eclipse.org/JDT/Eclipse_Java_8_Support_For_Kepler) с поддержкой Java 8 для Kepler.